# Order by different field based on criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two series of posts. Each post has some percentage of progress (`project_percent`) and a end time (`end_date`). I want to first show posts with `end_date` in the future ('DESC') and after that I want to show project with `end_date` in the past order by percent. How can I do this with just one query?

(If date is not pass percent not important and just date is important  but if date passed I wanna sort by percent)

`select * from posts ...`

```
--------------------------------------
| post    | end_date  | project_percent|
| P1      | 28-10-2016| 50            |
| P2      | 26-10-2016| 40            |
| P2      | 30-10-2016| 20            |
| P3      | 24-10-2016| 75            |
```

* today is `27-10-2016`

I want the output to be like this:

```
--------------------------------------
| post    | end_date  | project_percent|
| P2      | 30-10-2016| 20            |
| P1      | 28-10-2016| 50            |
| P3      | 24-10-2016| 75            |
| P2      | 26-10-2016| 40            |
```

*The first two sorted by date and the second two sorted by persent

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Do you mean 'would like to'?

Comment: So you would like to first order by `end_date`, and then `percent`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. *just date is important not important*?

Comment: @BenM Sorry! If date is not pass percent not important and just date is important. but if date passed I wanna sort by percent

Comment: Can you add your desired result sets to the question. It's still not clear what you're asking I'm afraid.

Comment: @BenM OK. I do it now.

Comment: The first two sorted by date and the second two sorted by persent. 
You can have an UNION query the first with LIMIT 2 ordered by date, and the second UNION query you use the offset of 2

Comment: @SanderVisser I know :) . but the situation demands I use just one query!

Comment: Hmmm damn situations ;) what about a `ORDER BY CASE (true) THEN end_date ELSE project_percent`

Comment: @SanderVisser Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
select *, end_date < now() as flag from posts
order by flag
, case when flag = 0 then end_date end desc
, case when flag = 1 then project_percent end desc;
```

Could make it simpler by using

```
select * from posts
order by 
    case when end_date < now() = 0 then end_date end desc
    , case when end_date < now() = 1 then project_percent end desc;
```

but the first version is nicer for debugging.

Comment: Greate! Thank you.